# ArrayList of arrays get index

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of arrays and i want to change the value of 5

```
 List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] arr1 = {2,4,6};
    int[] arr2 = {1,3,5};
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);

    for (int[] ss : list) 
    {
         for(int sd : ss)
         {  
            //System.out.println(sd);
            if(sd == 5)
            {
             System.out.println("Yes");
             //change 5 to 12
             //list.set(list.indexOf(5), 12);

            }
         }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));

    }
```

[2, 4, 6] [1, 3, 5]

I want to change 5 to 12

Comment: (list.get(1))[2] = 11111;

Comment: I see you have already done that. What problems do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to :

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] arr1 = { 2, 4, 6 };
    int[] arr2 = { 1, 3, 5 };
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);

    for (int[] ss : list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(sd);
            if (ss[i] == 5) {                     // if current value is 5
                System.out.println("Yes"); 
                ss[i] = 12;                       // set it to 12 

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));

    }

}
```